# colorpicker, can't set listener

Tags: java, android, listener

I'm quite new to Java. I'm programming an app to cooperate with Arduino through UDP protocol.
I would like to use this colorpicker https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker 
but I'm unable to interact with it

I tried using setOnColorSelectedListener with the following code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ColorPickerView colorpicker = findViewById(R.id.colorpick);
    colorpicker.setOnColorSelectedListener(new OnColorSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onColorSelected(int selectedColor) {

        }
    });
}
```

But it gives me this error:

> Cannot resolve method 'setOnColorSelectedListener(anonymous
>   com.flask.colorpicker.OnColorSelectedListener)'

Does anyone have some experience with this library?
Please let me know if you know how to solve it.

Comment: I put the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method: `setOnColorSelectedListener`  does not exists.

Just read the source code, there are many samples:

```
ColorPickerView colorPickerView = (ColorPickerView) findViewById(R.id.color_picker_view);

        colorPickerView.addOnColorChangedListener(new OnColorChangedListener() {

            @Override public void onColorChanged(int selectedColor) {

                // Handle on color change

                Log.d("ColorPicker", "onColorChanged: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(selectedColor));

            }

        });

        colorPickerView.addOnColorSelectedListener(new OnColorSelectedListener() {

            @Override

        public void onColorSelected(int selectedColor) {

            Toast.makeText(

                    SampleActivity2.this,

                    "selectedColor: " + Integer.toHexString(selectedColor).toUpperCase(),

                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, You've saved me a lot of time

Comment: No problem, I don't know why my answer received a downvote :/

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo.

setOnColorSelectedListener should be addOnColorSelectedListener; there can be multiple listeners, so we are adding to the list of listeners rather than replacing the one true listener.

Comment: But the accepted answer did not explain what the problem is, it just copied and pasted some code without context. It's a low-quality answer.

Comment: The problem is clear, that method doesn't exist , I put the correct methods

Comment: I see I encouraged you to improve your answer. Good.